# Multiple screen

Tags: windows, display, vga

**How may I force my windows to think, that it has 2 screens connected?**

Hi. I love to use extended screen (2 screens connected to 1 graphic card, different images on each screen). But today, the second screen has broke down.

Is there any possibility to make my computer think, that it has still 2 displays connected? I will view the second screen on my old notebook, using TeamViewer (This software has an ability to choose, which screen do I want to display on remote computer).

I heard of a secret Windows directory called `\\DEVICES`. I'd like to write a very simple software that would emulate an external screen so I can display it using TeamViewer on the old notebook.

Any ideas? Thanks for your time

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I do not know about `\\DEVICES` and I never heard about it.
But as a workaround you can use tools like [Synergy](http://synergy2.sourceforge.net/) that allow you to control a PC from another by sliding your mouse from one screen to another.
Then you can just place your computer screens next to each other and switch from one to the other with just one mouse and one keyboard.

You can argue that is does change that you have to run processes on the first and second computer and you are right. But no ideas to emulate a screen.

Comment: So, basically, with Synergy I will have more desktops, but only on 1 display... just like in Linux. Am I right? If so, then that's **not**, what I was looking for. I prefer using `Yod'm` for that purpose.

Comment: No you will have two PCs, one screen per PC (so total is 2) and navigation with only one mouse and one keyboard. You can have as much PC (theoretically) as you wish with still just one mouse and one keyboard.

Comment: oh... I see. It looks great! I will test it soon. As well, as zoneos.

Answer (score 0):

there's a handful of tools that do roughly what you want in essence , but not quite using the same method. While [maxivista](http://www.maxivista.com/) comes to mind first, [zoneos](http://www.zoneos.com/zonescreen.htm) is a free software that does about the same - the method they use seems to be to have a modified driver, which then sends over the information via some protocol to a VNC or other client.

Presumably you could then set teamviewer to see this screen- but with built in capabilities to send that screen over, there may not be a point.

So, it can be done, but not quite the way you see it.

Comment: I took a quick look on this, it should be great. I will probably install one of them this evening.